# Homebrew won't install anything and I can't install gradle manually

Tags: gradle, homebrew

I'm trying to install gradle so I can use a  `build.gradle` file on my java program. This should be able to be done with a simple `brew install gradle`, but that gives errors.

So, i manually installed, but whenever I do `gradle -v` or `gradle -version`, it says `-bash: gradle: command not found`. So my main question is how can I fix homebrew so that it will actually install things for me, and if that can't be answered, where did I got wrong manually installing?(after putting gradle unzip in correct `opt/gradle` dir, modifying `.bashrc`, etc)

here is a sample attempt at homebrew install and the output:

```
$ brew install gradle
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `block in parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `each'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `flat_map'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `parse'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:8:in `initialize'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:106:in `new'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:106:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:17:in `require_relative'
    from /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/brew.rb:17:in `<main>'
```

When I type `gradle -v` or `gradle -version`, I should see that I do in fact have gradle, and that I can use it to build me java projects.

Comment: What is the output of `brew doctor`? Which version of macOS?

Comment: Have you tried brew update followed by brew install gradle

Comment: Just an update, I found a way to get gradle installed, so now I'm just trying to fix homebrew. @KannappanSirchabesan I did try that and it didn't work.

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni I am on mojave, macOS 10.14.2, but I can't output my brew doctor because stack overflow is saying the comment would be too long, but this is the first line /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/PATH.rb:71:in `split': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)

Comment: @ArisEmery It's better to edit your question than to add long comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your Homebrew installation seems broken. Try to uninstall it with:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/uninstall)"
```

and reinstall it with:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: tried that, doesn't work, still all the same issues after

Comment: I've modified my answer. Please try again, by using `/usr/bin/ruby` at the begin of each command.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add for anyone getting stuck on the first issue of having gradle installed but not being able to run `gradle -v` or `gradle -version`.

This is an indication that your 'PATH' environment variable has not been added.

You need to add your Gradle directory as a 'PATH' environment variable. 'PATH' environment variables are how all commands and executables are searched for in the terminal. Type `echo $PATH` in the terminal to see a list of colon-separated Directories that your commands and executables come from.

The solution depends on your shell language, for zsh:

1. Open Terminal
2. Open a zsh configuration file in a text editor or in nano:

   `nano ./zshrc`
3. If this file doesn't exist, *sometimes due to updating Zsh from Bash*, create it first:

   `touch .zshrc`
4. Add Gradle Bin Directory as a'PATH' environment variable:

   `export PATH=/path/to/gradle/version/bin:$PATH`
5. Save and close file with `Ctrl + X`, then `Y`
6. New terminal windows will automatically use this configuration file but to use the configuration file in the current terminal window type:

   `source ~/.zshrc`
7. You can confirm gradle is now available by entering:

   `gradle - v`